# Prestashop bin/console do not show output

Tags: php, symfony, command, prestashop

We are working on prestashop 1.7.5.1 / Php 7.3.
Website is working well. But we are not able to get bin/console output.

Command like `php bin/console list -vvv` has no output...

Any idea how we could enable console output for symfony commands ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of "php -v" ? can you confirm your server-wide php version is the same used by Prestashop (v.7.3) ? For instance, Centos 7 is shipped with PHP 5.4.45 and you'll need to specify the absolute path of the "alternative" PHP 7.3.